# mysql #1054 Unknown column using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE tblUser (
  User_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  User_Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  User_Password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (User_ID)
);

INSERT INTO `tblUser` (`User_Email`, `User_Password`) 
VALUES (`user1@local.com`, `password`);
```

> *Unknown column 'user1@local.com' in 'field list'*

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of backticks for strings.

```
INSERT INTO `tblUser` (`User_Email`, `User_Password`) 
VALUES ('user1@local.com', 'password');
```

Check **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)** for more explanation.

And I really hope that your **passwords are hashed**.